# Занесение value из Attribute в переменную типа enum

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Всем привет. Пытаюсь внести value из enum member в свою переменную типа Enum.
Правильно понимаю, что "In-House" не может быть внесено в качестве переменной или можно как-то привести??

```
public class ReservationCard
{      
    public ReservationStatus ReservationStatus { get; set; } 
}
```

//

```
public enum ReservationStatus
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "In-House")]
    InHouse = 1,
}
```

//

```
private static readonly ReservationCard ReservationCard = new ReservationCard
{
    ReservationStatus = ReservationStatus.InHouse  // now it's 1. Should be - "In-House"
}
```

Comment: Все у вас правильно. в статическом поле `ReservationCard` будет лежать переменная, у которой значение `ReservationStatus == ReservationStatus.InHouse`. Что вы имеете ввиду под `"In-House" не может быть внесено в качестве переменной`?

Comment: Сейчас у меня внесено value enum. И значение моей переменной = **1**. 
А мне нужно Value из enum member attribute, хочу чтобы моя переменная была равна = "**In-House**". Я не знаю как этого добиться.

Comment: `now it's 1. Should be - "In-House"` — почему вы так считаете? Какая ваша _настоящая_ проблема? Сериализация в JSON? Вывод в UI?

Comment: @КириллФилободченко вы точно понимаете, для чего используется атрибут `[EnumMember]`? Мне не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System.Reflection;
```

```cs
public static class ReservationStatusExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this ReservationStatus @this) => 
        typeof(ReservationStatus).GetField(@this.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>().Value;
}
```

```cs
static readonly ReservationCard ReservationCard = new ReservationCard
{
    ReservationStatus = ReservationStatus.InHouse.GetString()
}
```

Валидация отсутствует.

Результат `ReservationStatus.InHouse.ToString()` обязан быть `"InHouse"`, т.к. в таком случае мы можем по имени поля получить информацию о нём. Если вы не хотите использовать медленный `Enum.ToString`, то можете передавать сразу имя поля (предварительно нужно изменить реализацию `ReservationStatusExtensions.GetString`), т.е.

```cs
static readonly ReservationCard ReservationCard = new ReservationCard
{
    ReservationStatus = ReservationStatusExtensions.GetString("InHouse")
}
```

...или сделать вот так:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class ReservationStatusExtensions
{
    static readonly Dictionary<ReservationStatus, FieldInfo> fields = new() {
        [ReservationStatus.InHouse] = typeof(ReservationStatus).GetField("InHouse")
        // ...
    };

    public static string GetString(this ReservationStatus @this) => 
        fields[@this].GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>().Value;
}
```

Comment: В любом случае метод GetString() возвращает string параметр и возникает ошибка конвертации, потом что ReservationStatus не типа string.

Comment: @КириллФилободченко В типе `ReservationCard` исправьте у поля `ReservationStatus` исправьте тип с `ReservationStatus` на `string`.

Comment: @КириллФилободченко вы либо храните число, либо храните строку. можете создать 2 поля аля `ReservationStatus` и `ReservationStatusString`

Comment: Нет, изменить поле на string я мог с самого начала. Мне было интересно, можно ли так сделать с полем типа Enum

Comment: @КириллФилободченко как вы думаете, каким образом можно хранить число и строку в 1-м поле? можете использовать `object`, но зачем хранить *строку* в *числе*?!